# Getting information from a website using python

Tags: web

I am new to python. I am trying on a project with my friend, where we need to extract the runs a batsman scored in his last match. But we are stuck at how to get that info using python. What we know is getting the source code of the web page. How to go one step further. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It's important you show what you have so far so people can help. The brief description you have so far is far to broad and unclear. Use the edit link at the bottom to expand on your question. Have a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to find out how to ask,

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `requests` package:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests
From the site:
Requests is an Apache2 Licensed HTTP library, written in Python, for human beings.

Most existing Python modules for sending HTTP requests are extremely verbose and cumbersome. Python’s builtin urllib2 module provides most of the HTTP capabilities you should need, but the api is thoroughly broken. It requires an enormous amount of work (even method overrides) to perform the simplest of tasks.

Things shouldn’t be this way. Not in Python.

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com', auth=('user', 'pass'))
>>> r.status_code
204
>>> r.headers['content-type']
'application/json'
>>> r.text
...
```